# No view found for id for fragment YoutubePlayerFragment

Tags: android

I am facing the above error from last one day.(I check the same code and worked in sample project with same recyclerview code) not sure why it is happened with this.
I am using Recyclerview to display youtubeplayerfragment which is replacing with Framelayout in OnBindViewHolder.

```
<FrameLayout        
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />
```

and in OnbineviewHolder method

```
 YouTubePlayerFragment ytFrag =  new YouTubePlayerFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout,ytFrag);
            transaction.commit();
```

I could not resolve this issue.
I tried using support.v4.app.FragmentManger with YoutubePlayersupportFragment, but no luck.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have to use <fragment tag instead of FrameLayout tag.

Comment: Hi Surender, I tried that also but same error occurred.

Comment: @SurenderKumar, that is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chatBoxWelcomeTop"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chatBoxWelcomeTop"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

added layout_marginBottom = "10dp" & height should be match_parent
Because when youtube video loaded it does not have enough place to load and giving no view found error.